# How to get values from database, and insert inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have my facebook share scritp:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#share_button').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            FB.ui(
            {
                method: 'feed',
                name: 'This is the content of the "name" field.',
                link: ' http://www.hyperarts.com/',
                picture: 'http://www.hyperarts.com/external-xfbml/share-image.gif',
                caption: 'This is the content of the "caption" field.',
                description: 'This is the content of the "description" field, below the caption.',
                message: ''
            });
        });     

    });  
  </script>
```

But, i want to get the values of "name", "link", "picture" and others from a database, maybe an simple access mbd file. I will use Classic ASP for the conection with this database...

There is a way to do that?

Comment: Where is this database located?

Comment: at the same folder of my page... or inside a folder caled "database".. the locate does't matter... i think...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a server side script (using for example php/mysql or asp.net, ...) that reads the values you need from the database and outputs them in JSON format for example, then use ajax to get the script's JSON output and use the response values to create your FB object

Answer (score 0):

Really, really simple python server using [cherrypy](http://www.cherrypy.org)

```
import cherrypy
import json

names = ['Bob'] // List of names. You call fill this from a DB
class BasicServer:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def names(self):
        return json.dumps(names) // Returns a JSON list of names from the DB.

cherrypy.quickstart(BasicServer())
```

Really, really basic request from server.

```
$('#share_button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var names = null;
    // Request all the data you want from the server.
    $.when($.get('serverAddress/names', function(data) { names = data; }))
       // When all your requests are done, call your FB.ui function.
      .done(FB.ui({name: names[0]}); // Just selects the first name ('bob')
}
```

What it really sounds like you want is some sort of templating engine. This way you can **serve your page** with data **prefilled**. Since the example here is python, have a look at libraries like [MAKO](http://www.makotemplates.org/) or [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i use Classic ASP to get the values from database. I don't know "python"... :)